# how to set time for opening toolkit contextmenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

Here I am using toolkit context menu in my listbox data template when user long press or hold on listbox item it opens a context menu  but take long time to open and sometimes long press miss. Please give me any solution.

```
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu> 
   <toolkit:ContextMenu> 
       <toolkit:MenuItem Click="AddMenuItem_Click" Header="Add"/>            
       <toolkit:MenuItem Click="DeleteMenuItem_Click" Header="Delete"/> 
       <toolkit:MenuItem Click="UpdateMenuItem_Click" Header="Update"/>   
   </toolkit:ContextMenu> 
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```